# Docker packet filtering?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS,  docker-ce version 24.0.2

so here's the connundrum....

From the host I can do curl https://8.8.8.8 which returns back a 302 code which is fine shows I was able to hit it on 443.

I grabbed a container from here:  wbitt/network-multitool:alpine-extra

Within that container,  If I do a the same curl command I get

```
curl -v https://8.8.8.8
Trying 8.8.8.8:443...
connect to 8.8.8.8 port 443 failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 8.8.8.8 port 443 after 0 ms: Connection refused
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 8.8.8.8 port 443 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Now ping works,  dns lookups work.
There are NO firewalls running.
This is an EC2 instance, but the security group on this instance is wide open for outbound traffic.

Here's some extra info.  So if I change the network from bridge,  to host the container works fine.  Which I suppose since the host works 100% that's not a surprise.

I suspect some weird artifact, either configuration or package installed is messing this up.  This server had ubuntu's version of docker installed and that was removed and then an install from docker's repo was done.
Now to compare,  I spun a fresh EC2 ubuntu image (same base AMI as this one that doesn't work) up installed docker from docker's repo and it just works 100% like it should.

But I am very keen to understand WHY one works and one does not.  I have compared ip tables, did a docker network inspect on the network the container attaches to in bridge mode and the two servers (working and not working) are identical.
If I run nmap within the container on the server that DOESN'T work.

```
/ # nmap 8.8.8.8
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-06-30 21:46 UTC
Nmap scan report for dns.google (8.8.8.8)
Host is up (0.00075s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
53/tcp  open   domain
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp closed https
```

Container on server that works

```
/ # nmap 8.8.8.8
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-06-30 21:48 UTC
Nmap scan report for dns.google (8.8.8.8)
Host is up (0.0031s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE SERVICE
53/tcp  open  domain
443/tcp open  https
```

for reference, I am starting this with:  docker compose -f ./network-tools.yml up -d
network-tools.yml file....

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  network-tools:
    image: wbitt/network-multitool:alpine-extra
    container_name: network-tools
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 #optional
      - 3001:3001 #optional
```

So it's like there is some packet filtering going on between the docker network and the host when in bridge mode. But I'm not finding anything around that.  I am somewhat new to docker, not to linux though.    If anyone has some suggestions I'm all ears as I don't like things I don't understand :)

Comment: bump.  anyone have any ideas here?